# Correct ussage of "what" and "which" in a sentence. And second sentence ussage of "what's going on"

Tags: sentence-construction

A sentence:
**Let's enjoy a freedom in *which/what* you can be.**

What is a correct?

Second question - sentence:
**What is going on,
on your mind.**

Is it possible to use it this way?
Let's say, that I sing: *What is going on* "a pause here, and continuing" *on your mind?*

IS it possible to use it this way?

Thanks guys for helping :)

Comment: What is going on in your mind? But: What's on your mind. Your first sentence is not comprehensible. :)

Comment: In written English or in speech, these would be considered incorrect (freedom is not countable so no "a"; the verb "be" needs a complement; the meaning of "on your mind" doesn't fit with the rest of the sentence)  But if you're singing a song, nobody really cares about the words making sense, as long as you sing in tune.  Correcting lyrics is not a task for this forum'

Comment: 1. Neither is correct because the sentence doesn't make sense. 2. On this site, we can only ask one question at a time. If you really want to ask both questions, start a second question. Keep in mind though, that asking for proofreading is also not allowed. Please only ask questions about aspects of the English language, rather than specific sentences